# Moving a slider to change resolution

Tags: c#, image, xna, draw

I am have a small problem with a sliding image change an image to display a different resolution to the right of it. when the resolution is set accordingly there is an OK box that the user must press to change the resolution. as I move the slider across the background shown here:

[image]

the slider works by having a max and min int for the slider to stop at. since the image is placed by the top left of the image the min (witch is to the far right) is located on pixel over from the tall white line to the left, and the same for the max. I use 2 classes at this time when redrawing and placing images, an `Options` class and the main class `Game1`. The `Options` class holds a draw method and moves it over to the main class to draw on the screen.

Options.cs (Draw method):

```
public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res1, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res2, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res3, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res4, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res5, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res6, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res7, res, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res8, res, Color.White);
}
```

I want to call on these image when the pointer is in the correct position so I edited the the code above to look like this:

```
public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
    if (slide3.X >= options.resStart && slide3.X <= options.resEnd)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res1, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res2Start && slide3.X <= options.res2End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res2, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res3Start && slide3.X <= options.res3End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res3, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res4Start && slide3.X <= options.res4End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res4, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res5Start && slide3.X <= options.res5End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res5, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res6Start && slide3.X <= options.res6End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res6, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res7Start && slide3.X <= options.res7End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res7, res, Color.White);
    else if (slide3.X >= options.res8Start && slide3.X <= options.res8End)
        spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res8, res, Color.White);
    else
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.font1, "ERROR!!!", new Vector2(res.X, res.Y), Color.White);
}
```

What happens is that the images will output the "ERROR" if I run the program. I guess the problem will be a quite silly mistake from my inexperience and am still learning.

Comment: what I could do make an string value and make it so that the update does the if else statements, then just make it so that if string is equal to name that I put, then draw image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, I needed to move the if else statements over to the main function's update method, having the string there I was able to simply copy it over. I would have preferred to keep it in the `Options` class and not adding it to the main class.

```
if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.resStart && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res2Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res1";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res2Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res3Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res2";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res3Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res4Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res3";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res4Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res5Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res4";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res5Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res6Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res5";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res6Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res7Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res6";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res7Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res8Start)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res7";
else if (StartUp.Options.slide3.X >= options.res8Start && StartUp.Options.slide3.X <= options.res8End)
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Res8";
else
    StartUp.Options.resLocation = "Error";
```